# MVC Cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I was wondering if I can do this or is there other way to do it?
I build it without problems but when I run it it says:

> CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.RoundPanelSettings' because it is not a delegate
>   type

Code:

```
@Html.DevExpress().RoundPanel(RPsettings =>
{
    RPsettings.Name = "rpnlNewUpdateConfigs";
    RPsettings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    RPsettings.ShowHeader = false;
    RPsettings.SetContent(() =>
        {
            Html.DevExpress().CallbackPanel(CBsettings =>
            {
                CBsettings.Name = "cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs";
                CBsettings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
                CBsettings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Storage", Action = "Storage" };
                CBsettings.SetContent(() =>
                    {
                        @<table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>Type:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(cboxsettings =>
                                                {
                                                    cboxsettings.Name = "cbType";
                                                    cboxsettings.Width = 180;
                                                    cboxsettings.SelectedIndex = -1;
                                                    cboxsettings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
                                                    cboxsettings.Properties.Items.Add("Path");
                                                }).GetHtml();
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>;
                        Html.DevExpress().Label(L1settings =>
                        {
                            L1settings.Name = "ErrorLabel1";
                            L1settings.Text = "Label1";
                        }).Render();
                        Html.DevExpress().Label(L2settings =>
                        {
                            L2settings.Name = "ErrorLabel2";
                            L2settings.Text = "Label2";
                        }).Render();
                    });
            }).GetHtml();
        });
}).GetHtml()
```

Any guesses?

Comment: RPsettings is class type not a variable, thats the problem! new RPsettings should work or a lambda variable like rPsettings!

Comment: Not working. If you check the DevExpress call back panel example, it work this way http://mvc.devexpress.com/CallbackPanel/

Comment: i did check, and they pass the settings as lambada no as the class, this way:  
"settings => {
        settings.Name = "cbpExample";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "CallbackPanel", Action = "ExamplePartial" };
        settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        settings.Height = 300;"

Comment: The problem disspaears when I remove all the .net code:<table>

Comment: @<table> did you noticed this @?

Comment: If I dont put the @, it wont know that my code changes to asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what happens. 
The asp.net tags are not allowed in the SetContent() that way.
The correct way to do it is:

```
CBsettings.SetContent(() => {
    ViewContext.Writer.Write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");

    ...

});
```

So sad the intellisense doesn't give a clue about what is wrong.

Comment: yep, in 2 days, cant do it yet